# Is it posible to check if a struct was defined before (in a header file) during preprocessor?

Tags: c

I want to check if a certain structure was defined in a header file I included and define it if it is not. The header might, or might not be included in the source file and that is (obviously) known at compile time.

Essentially I want something similar to the `ifndef` guards used in header files and I know that I could use a check if the header file where the `struct` is defined is included by checking it's guard, but I am wandering if I could check for the `struct` itself.

Comment: No, You cannot. Only thing you can do is to check if the header guard macro which defines the structure is defined or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have checked in ANSI C spec

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

here
Preprocessing directives only talk about identifier.

**so it is NOT possible to check that this structure is defined or not.**

Answer (score 9):

No. The preprocessor doesn't parse the C language itself, it knows nothing of the declared types.