# Avoid nested struct redefinition for linked lists in cython

Tags: python, c, linked-list, cython

I want to move code related to linked-list structure to separate file. This linked list is used in both .pyx and .c files.

Current realisation:
cython_file.pyx:

```
ctypedef struct linked_list

ctypedef struct linked_list:
    double price
    double volume
    int data
    linked_list *next_cell
...
```

c_file.c:

```
typedef struct linked_list {
    double price;
    double volume;
    int data;
    struct linked_list * next_cell;
} linked_list;
...
```

What I want is to create `LinkedList.h`, `LinkedList.c` and `LinkedList.pxd`, which will contain following content:

LinkedList.h:

```
typedef struct linked_list {
    double price;
    double volume;
    int data;
    struct linked_list * next_cell;
} linked_list;
...
```

LinkedList.c:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
...
```

LinkedList.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "LinkedList.h":
    ctypedef struct linked_list

    ctypedef struct linked_list:
        double price
        double volume
        int data
        linked_list * next_cell
```

I suppose to use this in following way:
in cython_file.pyx:

```
from LinkedList cimport *
...
```

and in c_file.c:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
...
```

When I try to compile the second variant I get an error:
`LinkedList.h(1): error C2011: 'linked_list': 'struct' type redefinition`

I suppose that this problem occurs because of nested structs

Comment: Do you have an include guard in your header file?

Comment: @LLJ97 No, sorry, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `redefinition errors` you have to use an include guard in your header files.

```
//LinkedList.h
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
...
#endif
```

Include guards are preprocessor macros that prevent multiple including of header files.

It basically checks if `LINKEDLIST_H` is defined. If so it skips everything in the `if` clause. Otherwise it defines it.

With that you avoid redefining your structs from your headers multiple times, which can be the cause for this error.

Comment: Should I add 
`#ifndef linked_list

#define typedef linked_list
...
#endif
```

Comment: I don't know your project structure but when I, for example, create a project named `test` and create `LinkedList.h` in the root directory, CLion automatically adds `ifndef TEST_LINKEDLIST_H` at the top. So you can see where it is going.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156425/is-it-posible-to-check-if-a-struct-was-defined-before-in-a-header-file-during they say it is not possible to find out whether the struct was defined or not

Comment: The upper comment is irrelevant. Include guard helped me, thanks